# Footer taking different sizes in different browsers

Tags: html, css, footer, sticky-footer

I am building an web application .

I have added a footer to the page .

The footer become larger in Firefox ( horizontally ). Any possible reasons ?

The footer is a sticky div as mentioned here - http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/

Container CSS -

```
.container{

    background: #ffffff;
    width: 90%;
    min-height: 100%;
            height: auto !important;
            height: 100%;

    background: #FFF;
    margin: 0 auto -60px;
    max-width: 1200px;/* a max-width may be desirable to keep this layout from getting too wide on a large monitor. This keeps line length more readable. IE6 does not respect this declaration. */
    min-width: 768px;/* a min-width may be desirable to keep this layout from getting too narrow. This keeps line length more readable in the side columns. IE6 does not respect this declaration. */

}
```

Footer CSS -

```
#footer {
        height: 60px;

        background-color: #F0F0F0  ;

    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto 0;

    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
        }
```

Comment: The footer is 90%, as is your .container, but .container has `max-width: 1200px;` The footer in the 2nd image is >1200px

Comment: Thanks !! I got it now . Cheers !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add these two property of footer element as of container element

```
#footer
{
max-width: 1200px;
min-width: 768px;
}
```

Comment: @mad.geek it's my pleasure to help you. could u plz mark it as answer now :P :)

Comment: yeaah . It doesnt allow me to accept till 5 mins are over . So waiting .. cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

remove  -60px in margin in css to solve this issue of fixed footer UI design

Comment: No . The -60px is to provide space for the footer to come at the bottom . It has nothing to do with left/right alignment.